# Are you familiar to the big query issue when there is no alias?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In CoolaData we work with huge amounts of data, supporting behavioral analytics. A query i just run generated wrong field names when in a select statement that does not contain aliases, i.e - "select a.dt, a.device_type from..."

What I have discovered is that instead of the following results: "a.dt" should be resulted in - "dt" and "a.device_type" should be resulted in - "device_type".
Big query wrongly results in different names i.e :"a.dt" is wrongly named "a_dt", and "a.device_type" is wrongly named  - "a_device_type".

Not working:

```
SELECT 1 AS Number_of_Records, Custom_SQL_Query.a_device_type AS 
a_device_type, Custom_SQL_Query.a_dt AS a_dt, FROM 
  ( SELECT a.dt, a.device_type, FROM ( SELECT DATE(event_time_ts) AS 
    dt, lp_device_type AS device_type, item_id AS item_id, FROM 
    coola_demo_v2_dataset.pv60_session) AS 
      a LEFT JOIN EACH ( SELECT item_id AS item_id, FROM 
        coola_demo_v2_dataset.arm_item_dim) AS b ON a.item_id = b.item_id GROUP EACH BY 
           1, 2 LIMIT 10) AS Custom_SQL_Query
```

Working:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT a.dt, a.device_type, FROM 
  ( SELECT DATE(event_time_ts) AS dt, lp_device_type AS 
    device_type, item_id AS item_id, FROM 
       coola_demo_v2_dataset.pv60_session) AS 
         a LEFT JOIN EACH ( SELECT item_id AS item_id, FROM 
           coola_demo_v2_dataset.arm_item_dim) AS 
           b ON a.item_id = b.item_id GROUP EACH BY 
             1, 2 LIMIT 10) AS Custom_SQL_Query
```

Are you familiar with this issue? is there an option to configure the BigQuery to act differently?

Comment: Please provide the two queries - with and without "aliases" as an EDIT (link below the question) to your Question.

Comment: Working: SELECT
*
  FROM (
    SELECT
      a.dt,
      a.device_type,
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(event_time_ts) AS dt,
        lp_device_type AS device_type,
        item_id AS item_id,
      FROM
        coola_demo_v2_dataset.pv60_session) AS a
    LEFT JOIN EACH (
      SELECT
        item_id AS item_id,
      FROM
        coola_demo_v2_dataset.arm_item_dim) AS b
    ON
      a.item_id = b.item_id
    GROUP EACH BY
      1,
      2
    LIMIT
      10) AS Custom_SQL_Query

Comment: it seems like  if you write the following select statement on top: "select a_dt from( .. " - you will get the error: "Field 'a_dt' not found; did you mean 'dt'?"
but if instead you will use - "select * from( .. " - you will get the write answer. As if there is a different between the schema behind the scenes and the presentation layer.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue described above is actually the feature :o)

1) When you don't explicitly supply alias - it is being constructed after dot notation with dot substituted to underscore

```
SELECT a.dt FROM( ..   --> a_dt in output
```

Above will produce output with a_dt named field

If you expect filed to be name as dt you should use below approach

```
SELECT a.dt as dt FROM( ..     --> dt in output
```

2)  If you need to reference field from sub- select  -

```
SELECT a_dt FROM( .. --> error
```

you still need to use dot notation like below

```
SELECT a.dt FROM( .. --> a_dt in output
```

or

```
SELECT a.dt as dt FROM( .. --> dt in output
```

3) So far, there is no any configuration that would change this for you (at least as I know of)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, The only issue I have with it is that when I give a freedom for my users to query my Big query DB, they try to do it from discovery tools such as Tableau, which generates a select a_dt.. on top of the select statement. This fails as you just showed.  do you find a special reason why BQ SQL basic functionality is different than i.e SQL Server,mysql, oracle etc.. ?

Comment: i can guess - the reason is to avoid ambiquity in naming of result's filelds. so you need to make sure you provide aliases